# "The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application" using spring boot and Azure AD

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory

I have build the application using spring boot and followed exact similar steps mentioned on
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory

but I am getting "The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '0eaef1b0-06fc-46af-b4db-beeab7b07069'." error.

Any leads or help is much appreciated.

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I have answered similar questions before.

There is a general solution to the problem of **not match**:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request URL, you will find redirect_uri, copy the value of redirect_uri and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

For the redirect URL, it should start with `https`, if you need to start with `http`, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.